# How to write a proper if statement in Python?

Tags: python

I made this simple Caesar Cipher program with Python that Encodes and Decodes words, all I want to do is to write an if statement for the user if they wrote a wrong word (anything other than "decode" and "encode") and tell them to try again, I kept trying and did a lot of researches I couldn't find anything that helped.. There are of course a lot of other ways of doing that, but I want to add that into my particular code rather than changing the code itself, which I don't know how..

Any help would be appreciated..

Here's my code:

```
#from art import logo
#print(logo)

alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def caesar(start_text, shift_amount, cipher_direction):
  end_text = ""

  if cipher_direction == "decode":
    shift_amount *= -1
  for char in start_text:
    if char in alphabet:
        position = alphabet.index(char)
        new_position = position + shift_amount
        end_text += alphabet[new_position]
    else:
        end_text += char
  
    
  print(f"\nHere's the {cipher_direction}d result: {end_text}")



should_continue = True
while should_continue:
    direction = input("\nType 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt: ")
    text = input("\nType your message: ").lower()
    shift = int(input("\nType the shift number: "))

    shift = shift % 26
    caesar(start_text=text, shift_amount=shift, cipher_direction=direction)

    result = input("\nType 'yes' if you want to go again, otherwise type 'no': ").lower()
    if result == "no":
        should_continue = False
        print("\nGoodbye!")
```

Comment: you need to remove unnecessary code and reduce it to just what the problem is. it has nothing to do with caesar cipher.

Comment: If I knew, I would, plus, I thought the whole code might help the reader to understand what I’m asking for.. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

```py
direction = input("\nType 'encode' to encrypt, type 'decode' to decrypt: ").lower()
if direction != "encode" and direction != "decode":
    continue
else:
    text = ...
    ...
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how or why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.